# Is it possible to use PackagingOptions configured per CPU architecture on Gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build-automation

I am using split to create different apks per architecture... the problem is that I am using a library that is generating some files on the /assets folder for two different architectures, and packaging them in all apks.... So I wish to use packagingOptions -> exclude on this files, but it should exclude different files on each architecture.

Is this possible?